# Django - Using request.POST in my view after override my form's __init__ method

Tags: django, forms, dynamic, view

Im doing a dynamic form using a ModelChoiceField, and i want to initialize it using the values of one of my DB tables. The problem it's that if i override __ init __ in the form, then i can't use request.POST in my view, and i need it to validate and extract user's selected option. So.. There's some way to use request.POST in my view after override my form's _ init __?

**FORM**:

```
categoria_formfield = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'size':'13', 'onchange':'this.form.action=this.form.submit()'}), queryset=sitio_categoria.objects.none())

def __init__(self):
        super(anadirComercioPaso1_form, self).__init__()
        self.fields['categoria_formfield'].queryset = sitio_categoria.objects.exclude(categoria='patrimonio').values_list('categoria',flat=True)
```

**VIEW**:
(This code raise __ init __() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) error.)

```
def panelComerciante_view(request):
        is_validated=False
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formulario_anadir_comercio_paso1 = anadirComercioPaso1_form(request.POST)
            if formulario_anadir_comercio_paso1.is_valid():
                is_validated=True
        else:
            formulario_anadir_comercio_paso1 = anadirComercioPaso1_form()
        return render_to_response('home/anadir_comercio_step1.html',{'formulario_anadir_comercio_paso1': formulario_anadir_comercio_paso1, 'pepe':pepe}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your `__init__` so it takes `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
...

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(anadirComercioPaso1_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You should now be able to pass `request.POST` as normal when you instantiate your form class.

Read more about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

Side note: Technically in Python class names should be [capitalised](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) rather than camel case :).